# Springboot with Elasticsearch Data to disable REST endpoints for specific entity

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch data and Springboot. It looks like Springboot exposes all REST endpoints of my resources. For example, my index pattern is "orders"

When I try to request "/orders", it returns the following:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "orders": [
      {
        "order_id": "adafagagagaga,
        "category": "test",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/orders/adafagagagaga"
          },
          "order": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/orders/adafagagagaga"
          }
        }
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "first": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/orders?page=0&size=20"
    },
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/orders{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "next": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/orders?page=1&size=20"
    },
    "last": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/orders?page=652&size=20"
    },
    "profile": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/profile/orders"
    },
    "search": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/orders/search"
    }
  },
  "page": {
    "size": 20,
    "totalElements": 13059,
    "totalPages": 653,
    "number": 0
  }
}
```

My Order class

```
@Document(indexName="orders", type="_doc")
public class Order {
}
```

OrderRepository class

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepositoy extends ElasticsearchRepository<Order, String> {    
    Page<Order> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

OrderController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public class OrderController extends BaseController {

    @Autowired
    private OrderServiceImpl orderServiceImpl;

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/page/{page}"})
    public Page<Order> findAll(@PathVariable Optional<Integer> page) throws Exception {

        int pageNum = page.isPresent() && page.get() == 0 ? 0 : page.get();
        return orderServiceImpl.findAll(PageRequest.of(pageNum, 5));
    }
}
```

OrderServiceImpl class

```
@Service
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {

    @Autowired
    private OrderRepositoy orderRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void setOrderRepository(OrderRepositoy orderRepository) {
        this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Page<Order> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        return orderRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }
}
```

How do I disable this endpoint? I wanted to use Pageable instead of this.

Comment: Which endpoint exactly do you want to disable?

Comment: this one "/orders", but the question is still "any endpoint"

Comment: I am a little bit confused to be honest. You want to disabled the /orders endpoint but define explicitely a request mapping for it in your OrderController class. Please be more specific.